# What the meaning of ^ for url

Tags: python, django

It might be too simple question.

I have this urlpatterns in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^s3direct/', include('s3direct.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

`localhost/admin` works, but `localhost/s3direct` shows the 404 error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8099/s3direct
Using the URLconf defined in djang_test.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^s3direct/
admin/
The current path, s3direct, didn’t match any of these.
```

(I use runserver at port 8099)

Comment: could it be that you meant `url(redirect/', include('s3direct.urls')),` instead of ``url(r'^s3direct/', include('s3direct.urls')),

Comment: `^` is regex term to mean something that starts with the pattern following it. Remove that term and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` in this case is a [Regex-specific operator](https://regex101.com/r/CNe1UZ/1), meaning that it only matches the beginning of the string.

I believe that your problem is that you actually need to request `http://localhost:8099/s3direct/` -- You're missing the trailing backslash

Comment: Thank you very much I need `/` at last